# How can I convert an ImageMagic shell command to an equivalent PHP script?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have the following shell script that I copied almost verbatim from the [ImageMagick manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/):

```
  convert input.jpg -background White -pointsize 32 label:'Hello world' +swap  -gravity Center -append output.jpg;
```

Now I want to run the same operation on a shared webhost (that does not seem to have the `convert` command available). On the surface the mapping from command line to PHP seems rather straightforward, but somehow it's not. The below code prints the input image unchanged.

```
//header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('input.jpg');

$image->setBackgroundColor("White");
$image->setPointSize(32);
$image->setGravity(imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$image->labelImage("hello world");
echo $image->count(); // 1
echo $image->appendImages(True);
//echo $image;
```

The `labelImage` function has very little documentation, and does not seem to do much at all. Furthermore, there is no `swap` function.

What is the equivalent PHP code for adding a caption on top of the image?

[edit]

It seems `labelImage` just sets a property, just like [`commentImage`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.commentimage.php)(example provided this time). There is a [`render`](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.render.php) command that looks promising, but gives an error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Imagick::render()`. Odd...

Comment: Imagick is working in a different way - not doing everything in one command so I assume it does not need a swap command. You just create the images in the correct order. I do not use Imagick but you are using $image for the original image and the label which maybe the problem. Also why not ask your hosts about Imagemagick? You might have to use something like usr/bin/convert instead of convert

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about label, but the second approach from the linked documentation using splice does translate over nicely:

```
$image = new Imagick("memes/$name.jpg");
$draw = new ImagickDraw();

$image->setBackgroundColor("White");
$image->spliceImage(0, 40, 0, 0);

$draw->setFillColor('black');
$draw->setFontSize( 28 );
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_NORTH);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 10, 0, $label);
```